# Finding SHA-1 in Android Studio 3.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I am trying to get the SHA-1, however, gradle>android>task>android>signingReport does not show it in Android Studio 3.0.1, can anyone help with this, please?

I am completely new to App development, I am following a tutorial, when they do the steps above they see the SHA-1 - they are using an older version of Android Studio.

[This is what I get when I run signingReport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4B7P.png)

Comment: what is shown when you follow your steps. ?? pls add screenshot

Comment: may be you have to look into `gradle console` for SHA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Click here]
Here I added a screenshot of my android studio 3.0.1. Please check it you will find some better idea.

Comment: This might sound like a stupid question, but how do I open the gradle console in the bottom right of your picture, please?

Comment: I found it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Follow this Image for creating SHA1 fingerprint

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Follow Below steps to get SHA-1 in Android Studio:

**Step 1:** Run your project.

**Step 2:** Click on gradle menu on right side

**Step 3:** Expand gradle task tree

**Step 4:** Open on android -> signingReport

**Step 5:** it will give you MD5 and SHA-1 in Run

Answer (score 0):

Follow [this](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/12/displaying-sha1-certificate-fingerprint.html) tutorial for creating SHA1 fingerprint

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you looking for result in the right place
http://prntscr.com/if3e86

Answer (score 0):

Open Your Project

Click on Gradle (From Right Side Panel, you will see Gradle Bar)

Click on Refresh (Click on Refresh from Gradle Bar , you will see List Gradle scripts of your Project)

Click on Your Project (Your Project Name form List)

Click on Tasks/Android

Double Click on signingReport (You will get SHA1 and MD5 in Run Bar)